# Как решить CommandAcceptanceException в интеграционном тесте?

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

Есть DAO метод который я тестирую при помощи `hsqldb`.

При создании `SessionFactory` падает `CommandAcceptanceException` при

```
SessionFactory fac = new AtomicReference<>(
                new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory()
        );
```

Лог:

```
Hibernate: alter table propose drop constraint FK1whqgtiifg9s1e1rxkuhbgqhk
2017-08-03T23:41:27.194+0300  WARN  GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
```

Мой `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:auto_mag;sql.enforce_size=false</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <mapping resource="ru/pravvich/model/User.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="ru/pravvich/model/Propose.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Почему возникает это исключение?

Как его убрать?

**UPDATE**

Вот пример теста

```
public class DAOImplTest {

    private SessionFactory fac;
    private DAO dao;

    private final User user = new User("test", "test");
    private final Propose propose = new Propose(
            user, "mark", "model", "desc", new byte[]{});


    @Before
    public void before() {
        fac = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

        dao = new DAOImpl(fac);
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        fac.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void whenAddNewUserAndGetUserByLoginPasswordThanUserExistInDB() {

        dao.addUser(new User("test", "test"));

        assertNotNull(dao.getUser("test", "test"));
    }
}
```

Comment: может тест интеГРационный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hibernate: alter table propose drop constraint
>   FK1whqgtiifg9s1e1rxkuhbgqhk

Похоже на [баг хибернейта](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7002) при использовании in memory  database. Который был исправлен в версиях: 4.3.0.Beta4.

Попробуйте поставить:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Хибернейт пытается дропнуть таблицы (из-за того: что выбрана стратегия create), которые не были созданы ибо база данных каждый раз создается с нуля.

---

Update:

> да это уберает ошибку но при этом подходе у меня тесты падают так как
>   они расчитаны на то что база должна пересоздаваться.

---

Воспользоваться аннотацией `@After`.
Если у Вас entityManager есть, то:

```
@After
public void after() throws Exception {
    if (entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
        entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
}
```

Или через datasource

```
@After
public void tearDown() {
    try {
        clearDatabase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail(e.getMessage());
    }
}


public void clearDatabase() throws Exception {
  DataSource ds = (DataSource) SpringApplicationContext.getBean("mydataSource");
  Connection connection = null;
  try {
    connection = ds.getConnection();
    try {
      Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
      try {
        stmt.execute("TRUNCATE SCHEMA PUBLIC RESTART IDENTITY AND COMMIT NO CHECK");
        connection.commit();
      } finally {
        stmt.close();
      }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        connection.rollback();
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Вариант с SessionFactory

```
public void clearDatabase() throws Exception {

   try (Session session = fac.openSession()) {
       Query query = session.createQuery("TRUNCATE SCHEMA PUBLIC RESTART IDENTITY AND COMMIT NO CHECK");       

       query.executeUpdate();

   } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
   } 
}
```

Comment: да это уберает ошибку но при этом подходе у меня тесты падают так как они расчитаны на то что база должна пересоздаваться.

Comment: Странно. Честно говоря не знаю как у Вас тесты создаются и запускаются, но добавил вариент, который может помочь в ответ

Comment: спасибо, я обновил вопрос и добавил пример теста. Я работаю через `SessionFactory`

Comment: Что если попробовать второй вариант? А получить сессию как-нибудь [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526556/session-connection-deprecated-on-hibernate)

Comment: попробовал с entityManager получается то же самое. А второй вариант к сожалению не как не реализовать в проеке нет спрингов а нужен SpringApplicationContext...

Comment: Закомментировать Spring. Вытащить коннекшен каким-нибудь способом как например  `connection = sessionFactory.getConnectionProvider().getConnection();` Или при **каждом** тесте необходимо обнулять БД ?

Comment: да в том то все и дело что нужно обнулять бд иначе самый первый ваш ответ отлично подошел бы просто стратегию с create  на update поменять

Comment: еще обновил ответ.

Comment: хм с вариантом с SessionFactory свалились все тесты. Я еще заметил одну деталь мой exception вылетает только тогда когда нет mem файлов. При запуске тестов hsqldb создает файлы mem.log, mem.properties, mem.script и пустую папку mem.tmp в корне проекта и при первом запуске вылетает exception и если они на месте то тесты проходят нормально. Возможно надо вызвать создание этих файлов с заранее и как-то удалять при окончании...